# PageSpeed Insights and blocking css > not getting anywhere

Tags: css, blocking, pagespeed

By now I have tried a lot of different things to get a better CSS score at PageSpeed Insights.

The critical css is inline, in the header and is okay. But the big style sheet is considered blocking.

I have tried and failed with the [rel method](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) (followed recommened example and checked it with the demo) and the method down below. The rel was working and so is the code below, but PageSpeed Insights is still saying it is blocking. Is there anything else I could try?

```
    <script>
        var loadCSSFiles = function() {
            var links = ["//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css", "../styles-secondary.css"],
                headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
                linkElement, i;
            for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
                linkElement = document.createElement("link");
                linkElement.rel = "stylesheet";
                linkElement.href = links[i];
                headElement.appendChild(linkElement);
            }
        };

        var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame || webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
        if (raf) {
            raf(loadCSSFiles);
        } else {
            window.addEventListener("load", loadCSSFiles);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Did you try defer attribute on <script> tag @Christien

Comment: @Adnan Akram, No i did not had defer, but I just added it and it did not change the score on Insights.

Comment: If it's possible can you share link so that i can check @Christien